# How to embed specific java modules into OSGi bundles? Is it even possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, java-module

Using java 11+, Eclipse, OSGi:

So, i have a "master" module in java. Basically, can be considered the main app module. From this module i dynamically access an OSGi implementation. (Right now, Apache felix, but it really shouldn't matter, i don't think.) I can then install/use OSGi bundles through that main app, and call on classes between the bundles if proper imports/exports are set. No problem.

My app module embeds the java.desktop and java.xml modules. Thus, all bundles i install have access to the classes within those modules (Swing, org.w3c.dom, etc.) -- and it works.

Now, what if i want to access code from a java module, say java.sql, from a new bundle, but i don't have that module (java.sql) embedded in my main module? How can that new bundle access the java.sql code?

Essentially, i get a class-not-found error every time i try to call on a module's code that i haven't first embedded in the main module. Via the Run Config i can set up my main module to embed those modules: java.desktop, java.xml, java.sql, or any others (via "requires" statements in the module-info file. How can i access new (non-currently-embedded) modules during runtime from later dynamically installed osgi bundles?

Is there some sort of bundle-config to embed specific java modules within a bundle, likening to the require statements in module-info?

Do i have to dynamically call on those new modules via some sort of service access?

Thanks much.

Comment: In contrast to the [Java Platform Module System (JPMS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) which uses the modulepath, in OSGi which uses its own class loader a bundle has a version and can be installed, started, stopped and uninstalled at runtime. This is why you cannot use a JPMS module as an OSGi bundle. You have either use JPMS or OSGi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [OSGi Connect Specification](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/8.0.0/framework.connect.html) and the [Apache Felix Atomos](https://github.com/apache/felix-atomos) project which implements OSGi Connect.

OSGi Connect defines mechanisms for mixed environments of JPMS modules and OSGi bundles to interact.

Comment: Thanks much for the feedback, Mr. Hargrave. This is likely the "answer." Unfortunately, i thought java+jpms+osgi couldn't get much more complicated. Apparently, I was wrong. *sigh* My hope is that someday jpms will absorb the functionality from osgi, and thus there will only be one layer to deal with for truly dynamic modules. But that's just a dream, isn't it.